# Find out if layers are empty

Tags: python, layers

Is there a better way, other than looping every object, of finding out if a range of layers are empty?

```
import bpy

layer_range = [1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14]
print("---------")
layer_range_break = False
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    for layer_number in layer_range:
        if obj.layers[layer_number]:        
            print("Object on bad layer")
            layer_range_break = True
            break
        else:
            print(obj.name)

    if layer_range_break:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using pythons's `any` and `all`**

In general, code like in your question can be shortened considerably using ptython's any or all methods. `any` is True if any item in a list is True, and `all` returns True if all are True.

In this case using `any` to determine if any object in the scene is on a designated layer.  `any(o.layers[l] for l in layer_range)` emulates your inner loop break.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
layer_range = [1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14]

dirty = any(any(o.layers[l] for l in layer_range)
            for o in scene.objects)        

print("Layer Range is dirty:", dirty)
```

PS: not sure this is "better", it is IMO more readable.